# How can I limit WiFi scanning on RPI3 to single channel?

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless

I am writing an code where my Pi is taking lot of time scanning on all channels. I have configured all my routers to same channel to save time. How can I limit my Raspberry Pi to scan all the routers on only one channel? Thereby saving time to scan?

Comment: The question is not quite clear - do you write a script (with iwlist) to scan Wifi? It probably depends on the tool/language  you use. If it is possible at all.

Comment: Is there a way, to do it? In a script or through terminal commands or through GUI, to tell my raspberry pi to scan only one channel? If so, please let me know. The code I have written does the scanning, and i want to reduce the scanning time. i want it to scan only the routers which I have configured on one channel only.

Comment: Now it is more specific question, maybe general to all linux. Try this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/scan-a-single-channel-to-measure-rssi-of-a-specific-ap-when-not-associated